# Comparing two text files and subtracting respective values

Tags: c#, file, file-comparison

I have 2 text files default.txt and current.txt.

default.txt:

```
ab_abcdefghi_EnInP005M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0009 FNMR: 0.023809524 SCORE: -4  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnInP025M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0039 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -14  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnInP050M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.01989 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -18  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnInP075M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0029 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -17  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnInP090M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0002 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -7  Conformity: True
```

current.txt looks like this

```
ab_abcdefghi_EnUsP005M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0041 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -14  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnUsP025M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.00710000000000001 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -14  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnUsP050M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0287999999999999 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -21  Conformity: True
ab_abcdefghi_EnUsP090M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0113 FNMR: 0 SCORE: -23  Conformity: True
```

What i need to do is to subtract values of current from default (default-current).

E.g:

```
FMR_DIFF = FMR(default) - FMR(test)
FNMR_DIFF = FNMR(default) - FNMR(test)
SCORE_DIFF = SCORE(default) - SCORE(test)
```

I need to output this in a text file with output looking something like this

O/P:

```
result:   005M3TSub FMR_DIFF: -0.0032 FNMR_DIFF: 0.023809524 SCORE_DIFF: 10
```

I am trying to do this in C#. So far i have tried reading lines in both files. I was able to compare them. I cannot comprehend the logic i need to implement. I am very new to programming. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, split it down into individual tasks - think about how you want to parse each line of text. (You say that current.txt has a different *structure* most of the time - what do you mean by that?)

Comment: @JonSkeet current.txt will definitely have the data that I mentioned above. But that's not always the only data that file might have. it might have some other data. Essentially i need to identify P005 values(if present in both. P005 may exist in one and not in the other) in both files and subtract them.

Comment: Well then you first need to work out how to identify the relevant lines. We have no idea what "P005 values" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting problem. Please check the solution. It is not optimized properly.

Firstly, we create a simple FileStructure Class to represent the String:

```
public class DefaultFileStructure
    {
        public string FileId;
        public decimal FMR;
        public decimal FNMR;
        public int Score;
        public bool Conformity;
    }
```

define the constant keyname for parsing .

```
private static string DEFAULT_KN = "tv_rocscores_DeDeP";
private static string TEST_KN    = "tv_rocscores_FrFrP";
```

Now, Parse the file and store the data in list structure.

```
    private List<DefaultFileStructure> GetFileStructure(string filePath, string keyName)
            {
                List<DefaultFileStructure> _defaultFileStructure = new List<DefaultFileStructure>();

                if(!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error in loading the file");               
                }else{
                    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                    foreach (string s in readText)
                    {
                        _defaultFileStructure.Add(ParseLine(s, keyName));                    
                    }
                }

                return _defaultFileStructure;
            }

private DefaultFileStructure ParseLine(string Line, string Keyname)
        {
            DefaultFileStructure _dFileStruc = new DefaultFileStructure();

            string[] groups = Line.Split(new[] { ' ', ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            /* -- Format Strucure, if the log provide same format always..
               Can also implement Expando concepts of C# 5.0 ***
                0[tv_rocscores_DeDeP005M3TSub.csv]
                1[FMR:]
                2[0.0009]
                3[FNMR:]
                4[0.023809524]
                5[SCORE:]
                6[-4]
                7[Conformity:]
                8[True]
             */

            _dFileStruc.FileId = groups[0].Replace(Keyname, "");
            _dFileStruc.FMR = decimal.Parse(groups[2]);
            _dFileStruc.FNMR = decimal.Parse(groups[4]);
            _dFileStruc.Score = int.Parse(groups[6]);
            _dFileStruc.Conformity = bool.Parse(groups[8]);

            return _dFileStruc;
        }
```

To match the difference and get the defined result as per your question.

```
 public void getDiff(String FirstFile, string SecondFile, string ResultFile)
        {
            try
            {
                //check if file exits....
                if (!File.Exists(FirstFile)) { return; }
                if (!File.Exists(SecondFile)) { return; }

                //Keep the result String..
                StringBuilder ResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                //Get the List of default file.
                List<DefaultFileStructure> DefaultList = GetFileStructure(FirstFile, DEFAULT_KN);

                //Get the List of test file.
                List<DefaultFileStructure> TestList = GetFileStructure(SecondFile, TEST_KN);


                //Get the diff and save in StringBuilder.
                foreach (DefaultFileStructure defFile in DefaultList)
                {
                    bool checkALL = false;
                    foreach (DefaultFileStructure testFile in TestList)
                    {
                        //Compare the file for diff.
                        if (defFile.FileId == testFile.FileId)
                        {
                            checkALL = false;
                            ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("result: {0} FMR_DIFF: {1} FNMR_DIFF: {2} SCORE_DIFF: {3}", defFile.FileId, defFile.FMR - testFile.FMR, defFile.FNMR - testFile.FNMR, defFile.Score - testFile.Score));
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            checkALL = true;                      
                        }                        
                    }
                    if (checkALL == true)
                    {
                        ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("result: {0} FMR_DIFF: {1} FNMR_DIFF: {2} SCORE_DIFF: {3}", defFile.FileId, "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"));

                    }
                }

                //File processing completed.
                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(ResultFile))
                {
                    outfile.Write(ResultBuilder.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Call the following method.

```
 getDiff(@"I:\Default_DeDe_operational_points_verbose.txt",
         @"I:\FrFr_operational_points_verbose.txt", 
         @"I:\Result.txt");
```

Thanks,
Ajit

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the values, you'll first have to parse them. You can create a class that represents a single line of (False / Non-False) MatchRates:

```
public class MatchRateLine
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal FMR { get; set; }
    public decimal FNMR { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public bool Conformity { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your parser you can have a method like this:

```
public List<MatchRateLine> ParseFile(string filename)
{
    var result = new List<MatchRateLine>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            result.Add(ParseLine(line));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And one way to do the actual parsing is this:

```
public MatchRateLine ParseLine(string line)
{
    var result = new MatchRateLine();

    int fmrPosition = line.IndexOf("FMR: ");
    int fmnrPosition = line.IndexOf("FMNR: ");

    string fmrValueString = line.Substring(fmrPosition, fmnrPosition - fmrPosition);
    decimal fmrValue;
    if (decimal.TryParse(fmrValueString, out fmrValue))
    {
        result.FMR = fmrValue;
    }

    // repeat for other values

    return result;
}
```

In the parser I have defined *"A line's FMR value"* being *"the text between 'FMR: ' and 'FMNR: ', parsed as decimal"*. You'll have to apply this logic for each value you want to extract.

Now when you have two collections, you can loop over them and compare their values and whatnot:

```
var defaultLines = Parser.ParseFile("default.txt");
var currentLines = Parser.ParseFile("current.txt");
```

---

Your actual question though seems to be that you probably want to compare specific lines in `default` and `current`, but you're having trouble identifying lines that belong to each other. As seen with `ab_abcdefghi_EnInP090M3TSub` in your `default` on line 5, and `ab_abcdefghi_EnUsP090M3TSub` in `current` it's on line 4 (note `In/Us`).

For this you can extend the `MatchRateLine` class with a property, where you store the filename or a substring thereof by its meaning so you can find unique lines in both lists by this value.

You can again use the `Substring()` method for this, in the `ParseLine()` method:

```
// Position:  0123456789012345678901234567890
// Filename: "ab_abcdefghi_EnInP090M3TSub.csv"

result.ReportCode = line.Substring(17, 6);
```

This will cause the resulting `MatchRateLine` to have a `ReportCode` property with the value `P090M3`.

Given the two lists of lines again:

```
var p090m3DefaultLine = defaultLines.First(l => l.ReportCode == "P090M3");
var p090m3CurrentLine = currentLines.First(l => l.ReportCode == "P090M3");

var fmrDiff = p090m3DefaultLine.FMR - p090m3CurrentLine.FMR;
```

Please note this code does a lot of assumptions on the format and can throw exceptions when the line being parsed doesn't match that format.

Comment: i might need some time to understand that.

Comment: @Matt yeah sorry I tend to overlook important details of questions, like _"I was able to compare them_" and _"I am very new to programming"_, and start typing happily away. Anyway check my updated answer, I've added some detail. Is my interpretation of the actual problem correct? I mean - do you have trouble identifying identical lines, do you have trouble determining which lines to output, are you unable to write a file?

Comment: I am sorry I troubled you more. I just commented cause i didn't want to be rude and not comment at all. I was getting my head around that. Thanks for the added detail. Again, apologies for additional trouble.

Comment: you understanding of my problem is spot on. That is exactly what i am doing.

Comment: I figured that out.. I deleted my comment :)

Comment: Sorry this took so long to accept the answer. I worked on my own version of your answer. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which lines must be in output: every "file".csv from default? every from current? Both (if one is missing in one of the 2 files, the output must still contain this csv)?

Once you know that, you can implement your logic:

- Create a class (named FileLine for example) with the properties of a
  line, that is to say: a string for name (name of this string: CsvName), a decimal for FMR (say FmrValue), a decimal for FNMR (FnmrValue), an int for SCORE (ScoreValue)
- Create a method for the process. It will:
- Check the structure of the Current file: if not valid, stop process
- Create a new List called defaultLines
- Create a new List called currentLines
- Create a string called processedLine (will be used in future step)
- Read Default file: foreach line, create a FileLine, parse the line and implement the properties of your FileLine, and add the fileLine to the list (defaultLines)
- Read current file: foreach line, create a FileLine, parse the line and implement the properties of your FileLine, and add the fileLine to the list (currentLines)
- Then process the comparison (see after)

  public void comparisonGenerator()
  {

  ```
  // HERE: add currentFile check

  // Initialization
  List<FileLine> defaultLines = new List<FileLine>();
  List<FileLine> currentLines = new List<FileLine>();

  // HERE: add file reading to populate defaultLines and currentLines 


  // Comparison
  foreach(FileLine item in defaultLines)
  {
      // for the item with the same name (using Linq, you could do it easily):
      FileLine cLine = currentLines.Single(l => l.CsvName.Equals(item.CsvName));
      if(cLine != null)
      {
          processedLine = String.Format("result: {0} FMR_DIFF: {1} FNMR_DIFF: {2} SCORE_DIFF: {3}", item.CsvName, item.FmrValue - cLine.FmrValue, item.FnmrValue - cLine.FnmrValue, item.ScoreValue - cLine.ScoreValue);
          // HERE: add this line to future output
      }
  }

  // When all lines are processed, write the output to a file using FileStream
  ```

  }

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I used best of both answers and i have my answer now.